# How to convert a bitmap photo to Hexadecimal color codes?

Tags: c#, hex, bmp, converters

I'm trying to create a program for my resume But I have a problem with converting **bitmap** photo that is **greyscale** photo to hexadecimal or better calls it the codes if the colors are anyone who can help me?

I tried to convert it with **base64string** but it didn't work.

```
openFileDialog1=new OpenFileDialog();
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

dlg.Title = "Open Image";
dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
     g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
}

// Convert the image to byte[]
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();

// Convert byte[] to Base64 String
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

// Write the bytes (as a Base64 string) to the textbox
textBox1.Text = base64String.ToString();
```

I expected to see a bunch of numbers like **A9C** or **255** but the thing that I saw is nothing.

Comment: The bytes of an image file are not colors. I guess you want to loop over all pixels? It is unclear exactly what result you want.

Comment: Try the [ByteViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer) control (.Net standard control). It allows you to view the content of a binary file in Hexadecimal and ASCII format. `using System.ComponentModel.Design; (...) ByteViewer viewer = new ByteViewer(); viewer.SetFile("Some File Path"); this.Controls.Add(viewer);`. You cannot edit the bytes values, though

Comment: @CrowCoder I'm sorry i couldn't Make My Question more clear.What i WAS Trying to say  is  that i want to see the photo's pixel's colors one A text Box Then Save THE TextBox For saving that i have no problem but for doing you that you can see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with .bmp files as in your code and gives AARRGGBB codes of pixels.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var colorCodes = this.GetColorCodes(dlg.FileName);
                    var str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                                          colorCodes.Select<int[], string>(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select<int, string>(code => string.Format("{0:X8}", code))))); // string.Format("{0:X6}", code & 0x00FFFFFF) if you want RRGGBB format
                    textBox1.Text = str; // requires textBox1.Multiline = true, better have monospaced font
                }
            }
        }

        private int[][] GetColorCodes(string path)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
            return Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Height)
                             .Select<int, int[]>(y => Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Width)
                                                    .Select<int, int>(x => bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())
                                                    .ToArray())
                             .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dear @Alex thank you for your help but the code that you've posted for me has a problem at the line  26 with the part `(" ", line.Select(code => $"{code:X8}"))))` id get some kind of error like this**Error 12 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\Users\Home\Desktop\New folder\Sample1_0\Experiment0_1\Form1.cs 41 64 Experiment0_1
** Can you help me more about this code .

Comment: @Armin Shabani, sure, I edited the code and specified type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You also may have problems with __$"{code:X8}"__ depending on language version. Then change it to __string.Format("{0:X8}", code)__.

Comment: Thank you dear @Alex but i still have problem with `(" ", line.Select<int, string>(code => $"{code:X8}"))))`Part And i Would be glad if you correct the answer or send it to my Gmail : batman1990ar@gmail.com Sorry for Bodering you my friend but i really need this code for my Resume.Thank you for your help any way...

Comment: @Armin Shabani, I suppose you to experience problems with string interpolation. Just use edited code.

Comment: thank you very much @Alex You help me very well. May The God Help You In your Life Like This My friend.

Comment: Thank you, @Armin Shabani. I wish you the same.