# I want to change the result of my program from Hexadeimal to Decimal Can Any One help me?

Tags: c#, decimal, bmp

I've read the bmp file and got a HexDecimal Result And Now I want To change 
the result to the Decimal only Can Any one Help ME???

I've Used These Codes So I get HEXDECIMAL Result:

```
private void ChosseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var colorCodes = this.GetColorCodes(dlg.FileName);
            var str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            colorCodes.Select<int[], string>(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select<int, string>(code => string.Format("{0:X8}", code))))); // string.Format("{0:X6}", code & 0x00FFFFFF) if you want RRGGBB format
            textBox1.Text = str; // requires textBox1.Multiline = true, better have monospaced font
        }
    }
}
private int[][] GetColorCodes(string path)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Height)
                     .Select<int, int[]>(y => Enumerable.Range(0, bitmap.Width)
                     .Select<int, int>(x => bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()).ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

I Got a Result in the text box like `FF` OR `00` BUT I need the decimal like 
`0` FOR the white color OR `255` For Black Color..

Comment: Investigate why you use `string.Format("{0:X8}", code)`, for instance look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: I understand Mr.@HansKesting  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have copied this code from somewhere and didn't know how to adapt it for your needs.

The line you need to change is this line:

```
colorCodes.Select<int[], string>(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select<int, string>(code => string.Format("{0:X8}", code)))));
```

`string.Format("{0:X8}", code)` formats the integers into hex. If you don't want hex, just do `ToString`:

```
colorCodes.Select<int[], string>(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select(x => x.ToString()))));
```

Comment: dear @sweeper yes i've asked another question on this website with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656218/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-photo-to-hexadecimal-color-codes?answertab=votes#tab-top) and i really needed it so now my boss ask me to change the hex to decimal. so i started to ask you my friend and of course THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but there is an error in `line.Select(int.ToString)` part and the error's text is **Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\Users\Home\Desktop\New folder\Sample1_0\Experiment0_1\Form1.cs 41 78 Experiment0_1
**  what should i do? and by the way i'm a newb in this language...